# Bridge Swift to Objective-C library "ono" using cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, cocoapods, alamofire

For my swift iPhone app I'm needing to parse XML.

I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and trying to use [Ono](https://github.com/mattt/Ono) which is an objective c library.  I used cocoapods to install Alamofire & Ono.

I've followed the steps here: [How to integrate Cocoapods with a Swift project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122914/how-to-integrate-cocoapods-with-a-swift-project)

where I have `#import <Ono/Ono.h>` in my bridging header.

Whats very odd is that in swift I can reference many of the Ono classes, but there is one function `XMLDocumentWithData` that I can't.  E.g. `HTMLDocumentWithString` I can call, but `XMLDocumentWithData` I can't.

Comment: XMLDocumentWithData / String are probably being slurped up as initializers by the automatic source bridge, since its name, `ONOXMLDocument +XMLDocumentWithData:` shares a common prefix and has an `instancetype` return type that would indicate that it is a constructor.

Comment: See if there isn't a stray `init` with a `data` parameter around.

Comment: yes!!!!  God bless the woman that gave birth to your brain! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mattt points out in his comment, somehow the code generation has "slurped" up the goods.

Below is how you can call the method instead for now:

```
let XML = ONOXMLDocument(data: data, error: &XMLSerializationError)
//let XML = ONOXMLDocument.XMLDocumentWithData(data, error: &XMLSerializationError)
```

Comment: For reference, it's the same automatic process by which `NSString +stringWithX:` constructors are bridged to `NSString(X:)` in Swift.

Comment: ah ok.  Sorry, I'm a newb didn't put that together for myself.  Maybe you could update the Alamofire documentation "Creating a Custom Response Serializer" to with ONOXMLDocument(data, error) instead.