# Swift iOS don't recognize GCM library imports?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-cloud-messaging

I downloaded GCM sdk through cocoapods successfully and everything is fine.
But Swift don't recognize GCM library imports

this image in Xcode:

[image]

and this Podfile :

[image]

how to fix this problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: I recommend Stefan Scoarta's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631364/171089) to add `use_frameworks!` to your podfile if you're targeting iOS 8 or higher and can use frameworks.

Original answer:
Make sure that you've configured a bridging header as described in Apple's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) document.

> To import a set of Objective-C files in the same app target as your Swift code, you rely on an Objective-C bridging header to expose those files to Swift…Alternatively, you can create a bridging header yourself by choosing File > New > File > (iOS or OS X) > Source > Header File.

There are some useful answers to a related question here: [How to integrate Cocoapods with a Swift project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24122914/171089)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a bridging header, in your pod file put this `use_frameworks!`. Then you can import the framework into your swift file.