# CorePlot with cocoa pods 0.38.2

Tags: swift, cocoapods, core-plot

I am trying to use `CorePlot` with `cocoapods` version `0.38.2`. I am pulling CorePlot using 
`pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.0'`

In my `bridging` file, I used

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
```

Here I am getting an error

> "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h" file not found.

Please tell me if there are any changes need to be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The podfile should include the `use_frameworks!` line. With Core Plot built as a framework, the import statement should be:

```
#import "CorePlot.h"
```

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122914/how-to-integrate-cocoapods-with-a-swift-project) for more troubleshooting tips for Swift projects that use Objective-C pods.