# Using Objective-c pod in Xcode 7.0.0 Swift 2 iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, cocoapods

I want to use this Objective C pod in my Swift project : [EAIntroView](https://github.com/ealeksandrov/EAIntroView)

[I found in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30331585/2305342) :

> Cocoapods 0.36 and above introduces the use_frameworks! instruction
>   which implies that the bridging header is not required for importing
>   Objective-C pods in Swift.

but I can't import `EAIntroView` and use the code of the Library

Here is my pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'PROJ' do
    pod 'Koloda', '~> 2.0.3'
    pod 'EAIntroView'
end

target 'PROJTests' do

end

target 'PROJUITests' do

end
```

Comment: What do you mean "You can't import"? Is there any errors from cocoapods or Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods compiled it as framework, try to use `@import EAIntroView`